# how to draw an arc line on google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi can someone help me with drawing an arc line exactly like uber does on google map?
I need to draw a ling which the quality doesn't decrease by zooming in and moving the map don't lead to lags...
I've seen this library

```
https://github.com/amalChandran/trail-android
```

I need smooth line exactly like uber
any help is appreciated...
like this picture

[image]

Comment: what is error in using that library?

Comment: @VishvaDave quality issue when zooming in and lagging when moving map quickly.

Comment: any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'//dependency, SphericalUtil has some functions to calculate heading, distance and offset between two point, may be this help you!

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private LatLng sydney1;
private LatLng sydney2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    sydney1 = new LatLng(-33.904438,151.249852);
    sydney2 = new LatLng(-33.905823,151.252422);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney1)
            .draggable(false).visible(true).title("Marker in Sydney 1"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney2)
            .draggable(false).visible(true).title("Marker in Sydney 2"));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney1, 16F));

    this.showCurvedPolyline(sydney1,sydney2, 0.5);
}

private void showCurvedPolyline (LatLng p1, LatLng p2, double k) {
    //Calculate distance and heading between two points
    double d = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(p1,p2);
    double h = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(p1, p2);

    //Midpoint position
    LatLng p = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(p1, d*0.5, h);

    //Apply some mathematics to calculate position of the circle center
    double x = (1-k*k)*d*0.5/(2*k);
    double r = (1+k*k)*d*0.5/(2*k);

    LatLng c = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(p, x, h + 90.0);

    //Polyline options
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();

    //Calculate heading between circle center and two points
    double h1 = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(c, p1);
    double h2 = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(c, p2);

    //Calculate positions of points on circle border and add them to polyline options
    int numpoints = 100;
    double step = (h2 -h1) / numpoints;

    for (int i=0; i < numpoints; i++) {
        LatLng pi = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(c, r, h1 + i * step);
        options.add(pi);
    }

    //Draw polyline
    mMap.addPolyline(options.width(10).color(Color.BLACK).geodesic(false));
}

}
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Thanks man but your code is like the rest on Stack...that's not a clear circle...the line with this method is drawn like a chopped circle...not smooth

Comment: any other ideas ?

Comment: here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661843/how-to-draw-uber-polyline

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928317/draw-a-curved-line-with-given-radius-and-two-locations

Comment: yes I've checked that ... same result...not what I said and not like UBER actually

Comment: any other ideas?